# Confused about jsp:param and scopes with JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I'm including a "child" JSP in a "parent" JSP with jsp:include and jsp:param.
I have a jsp:parameter parameter with `name="test"`, `value="testValue"`

`*c:out value="${test}"*` does *not* display anything (it's blank).
Only  displays `"testValue"`.

Why so ?
The official docs say that jsp:param add values to the request scope.
c:out is supposed to look at every scope (from narrow (page) to broader (application)).
Surely I must have missed something else ?

Comment: The docs say it adds a parameter to the URL; scopes are attributes.

Comment: Darn, you are right, the docs mention a request object, not a request scope. This is what I had misunderstanded, I guess ?

Comment: @DaveNewton I could pick your comment as an answer, if it posted as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, I didn't read the docs right, actually...the docs say it adds a parameter to the URL; scopes are attributes.

[Confused about jsp:param and scopes with JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270028/confused-about-jspparam-and-scopes-with-jstl#comment89518424_51270028)